# PHP Trigger date? xmas website preparation

Tags: php, date, date-comparison

I am prepping our businesses website for the Christmas period between November 1st until December 31st at midnight. I have already made the amendments on the sites CSS style-sheet to trigger the Christmas theme overwrite when the class of "xmas" is added to the body element if have placed the code I have for this into our global head.php file but it's triggering just now and I am trying to catch this within PHP tags to trigger with the date function?

Is this possible - If so could someone help?

So far I have tried this...

```
<?php
//Must be in format of DAY-MONTH-YEAR
if(date('d-j-Y') == "30-11-date('Y')") {
?>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').addClass('xmas');
});
</script>
<?php
}
?>
```

But of course this will only work on the 30th of November and I need this to work though until the 31st of December.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `DateTime` objects are they are comparable and make this fairly easy and straightforward.

```
<?php
$now   = new DateTime();
$nov1  = new DateTime('2015-11-01 00:00:00');
$dec31 = new DateTime('2015-12-31 23:59:59');
if($now >= $nov1 && $now <= $dec31) {
?>
```

If you want to make the code dynamic each year just make the year value dynamic as you have in your example.

Answer (score 0):

To have a script that whatever is the year or date, it always tell you if its time of xmas and new year eve holidays

i have use it in PHP

```
 /*
 * ==12 if is decembre, >= 17 if day is great than 17
 * ==12 if is january, <= 7 if day is less than 7
 * @return if is holiday time or not
 */
 public static function isHolidayTime()
 {

    if(date("m") == 12 && date("d") >= 17){
        //Holiday time there
      return true;
    }else if(date("m") == 1 && date("d") <= 7){
        //Holiday time there
      return true;
    }
    else{
        //normal day
      return false;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the date function with month and day, like so:

```
$date = date('md');
if($date >= '1130' && $date <= '1231')
```

Comment: How would I get this to work over the period of a month without having to update the code each day?